# Turn off Visual Studio/VB.Net lines around each method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio when working in VB.Net, it automatically creates lines/regions around methods etc.

How can this be turned off somewhere in the options?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you open Tools ==> Options, and select Text Editor, there is a "Basic" section for Visual Basic.  This option is on the "VB Specific" sub-section.  Unselect "Show procedure line separators".

Comment: In 2017 this option is under Basic>Advanced.

Comment: Can you turn it ON for other languages.

Comment: @NickG yes, it looks like there is an option for at least C#.

Answer (score 8):

Using **Visual Studio 2017 and above**

**For C# and Basic**

- Open  **Tools** > **Options** or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- At the top of the list search for **"Show procedure line separators"**
- select **Advanced**
- In  group  box  **Outlining**
- Uncheck **"Show procedure line separators"**

[image]

Comment: It only works if there is a blank line between methods, in C# at least.

Answer (score 7):

This is known as "Outlining Mode" and can be disabled by doing the following

- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor
- Navigate to the Basic -> VB Specific sub category
- Uncheck "Enable outlining mode"

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that comes across this and is using Visual Studio 2012.  Those lines are off by default.  If you want the lines back then you need to:

- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor
- Navigate to the Basic -> VB Specific sub category
- Uncheck "Enable outlining mode"

Yes, these are the same steps that JaredPar explained to turn the lines off.  However, it's completely backwards in 2012 and unchecking this option will bring the lines back.

Way to go Microsoft!

Comment: Again, if you WANT the lines:

In Visual Studio 2013 all the line options are on by default however the lines don't show up.  You have to go in and remove the check boxes, click ok then go back in and check them off again.  Then the lines will show up.

Even worse, you have to keep doing it as the lines will just disappear from time to time.  This has happened to me on multiple machines so clearly MS can't seem to get this issue fixed right.

Answer (score 2):

The menu sequence is a bit different for VS2015.

- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> Advanced
- Uncheck "Show procedure line separators."

Answer (score 1):

it was hard to find indeed, I was able to find it by looking for the word procedure. for vs 2022
[image]